# Why use Symfony's $request->query->all() instead of $_GET?

Tags: php, symfony, post, get

When using Symfony's HttpFoundation standalone outside the framework, why would you use `$request->query->all()` to get all `$_GET` values, rather than just simply use `$_GET` itself?

Since this Request component does not escape/clean `$_GET` values automatically, what is advantage of using `$request->query->all()` vs `$_GET` or `$request->request->all()` vs $_POST?

Comment: It makes your code Testable. You can test your controllers by mocking the request object.

Comment: @user2268997 put your comment as an answer

Comment: @Igor feel free to do that and extend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Request object to access this information makes you application more testable. Instead of having to ensure a particular global state before running each test, you only need to create a new Request object and set the values your test expects.